# Helper method to unpaginate all MS Graph API results

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Querying the MS Graph API, I use the following to page through the results and get *all* mail folders from a user:

```cs
var Client = new GraphServiceClient();
var folders = await Client.Users["id"].MailFolders.Request().GetAsync(); // returns IUserMailFoldersCollectionPage

var allFolders = new List<MailFolder>();
while (folders.Count > 0)
{
    allFolders.AddRange(folders);
    if (folders.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        folders = await folders.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

This works well. However, since different methods return different types, e.g. `IMessageAttachmentsCollectionPage` or `ITeamChannelsCollectionPage` and so on, I would like to have some kind of generic method I could pass all these CollectionPages in and return a list of all the unpaginated results.

I really am unfamiliar with generics and thus would like to ask for your help. Here;s what I tried this far.

```cs
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T2>> UnpaginateResult(ICollectionPage<T1> collectionPage, T2 outputType)
{
    var allItems = new List<T2>();
    while (collectionPage.Count > 0)
    {
        allItems.AddRange(collectionPage);
        if (collectionPage.NextPageRequest != null)
        {
            collectionPage = await collectionPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return allItems;
}
```

But this yields several errors:

Type or namespace T1 not found ...
Type or namespace T2 not found ...
ICollectionPage has no definition for NextPageRequest

What would be an elegant way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a working solution on [Github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/issues/42#issuecomment-510400507), sharing here so it might be also helpful to others.

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> UnpaginateResult<T, TPage>(Task<TPage> collectionPageGetter)
where T : Entity
where TPage : ICollection<T>
{
    var entities = new List<T>();
    var collectionPage = await collectionPageGetter as ICollectionPage<T>;
    var entityPageIterator = PageIterator<T>.CreatePageIterator(GraphServiceClientInstance, collectionPage, entity => { entities.Add(entity); return true; });
    await entityPageIterator.IterateAsync();
    return entities;
}
```